# Xampp with notepad++

Tags: xampp

I'm learning how to establish a localhost to a website that I'm building and testing in php. If anyone can help I will surely be grateful.
THIS A LINK TO SHOW SCREEN SHOTS:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dvAst-7T-gYGtmLhy76d3Y8LPsQDDp76

I have configured apache, MySQL, and FileZilla with NotePad++.
When I set the address bar to: `localhost/index.html', 'localhost:14147', 'localhost/index.php` or `127.0.01, 127.0.01:14147`, I get a "404" error.

I have searched through the questions and have found some possible answers, yet, when I troubleshoot the localhost connection I find the same error "404". This is what I have done so far:

- check port conflict.
- reconfigure ports
  which I have opened task manager and have checked ports with `netstat -o` which shows `PID:8460`, yet in task manager services `PID:8460` isn't showing.

Comment: I had to continue to troubleshoot which can be difficult on your own, yet, I want you to know that this is the solution that I have found the credits in searching and finding, yet, to the teacher, much appreciation. To God thank you.https://youtu.be/blmOFr8uZQI

Comment: Grammar, re-order paragraphs, so question can be found, and are in a logical order, code formatting, text formatting, edit sentences for clarity.

Comment: If you don't have enough reputation to embed images, please use image links that clearly show that they are indeed images.  Nobody wants to click on random unknown links.  Each image should be its own link (png, jpg, etc). Also, you *could* indicate what each image is for.  Once that occurs, another "editor" can verify your images, and embed them for you.